Map /@ with two arguments in which the first argument depends on the second argument
I have a question regarding the syntax of the /@ command.
I start with some list, say testlist = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}. I also have a function f that returns a list of lists (2-level list) with a similar structure. I want to apply this function f to the maximum of every element in the list and then append that same maximum value to every element of the resulting list that this function returns. In other words, the correct output that I want to get is:
{Append[#,Max[a,b]]&/@f[Max[a,b]], Append[#,Max[c,d]]&/@f[Max[c,d]], Append[#,Max[e,f]]&/@f[Max[e,f]]}

Is it possible to rewrite this as a map that would return this same result when applied to Max /@ testlist? In other words, I would like to write this as a map with two arguments such that one argument is a function that in turn depends on the other argument.
Edit. Artificial example. Let's assume that my function f is FactorInteger, as it also gives the same data structure. Let's assume the test input
testlist = {{100, 200}, {300, 400}, {500, 600}}.
Then my expected output should look like this:
{{{2, 3, 200}, {5, 2, 200}}, {{2, 4, 400}, {5, 2, 400}}, {{2, 3, 600}, {3, 1, 600}, {5, 2, 600}}}.
In other words, I apply to function to the maximum of every element of the list, and then every element of the resulting function output is appended with that maximum.

This just returns {f[Max[a, b]], f[Max[c, d]], f[Max[e, f]]}, so the same as f/@Max/@testlist.

I want every element of the result to be appended with the same Max[...] value that is taken as the input.

Assume that f[Max[a,b]] equals {x,y,z}. Then I want to get {x,y,z,Max[a,b]}as the first element of the resulting list.

To every element of the list I append at the end the value that was used as the argument of the function itself. Can do it with a Table[...], of course, but I wonder if there is an elegant way of writing it with /@.

The function f[...] also should take Max[...] as the argument. If I write it Join[{Max[#]}, f[Max[#]]] & /@ testlist, the Max is calculated twice. This is what I am trying to avoid.

So the result should be the same, but I want to calculate Max just once for all elements and then apply Join or Append to every element.

It would be best to provide expected output explicitly, but I think I understand, and maybe something like this would work. I've created a dummy function just for explicitness:
fn[_] := Array[x, {2, 2}];

Append @@@ Comap[{fn, Max}] /@ testlist
(* {{{x[1, 1], x[1, 2]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2]}, Max[a, b]}, 
    {{x[1, 1], x[1, 2]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2]}, Max[c, d]}, 
    {{x[1, 1], x[1, 2]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2]}, Max[e, f]}} *)

Or maybe you wanted the append-ing to happen at the lower level:
Apply[Map[Append[#2], #1] &] /@ Comap[{fn, Max}] /@ testlist
(* {{{x[1, 1], x[1, 2], Max[a, b]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2], Max[a, b]}}, 
    {{x[1, 1], x[1, 2], Max[c, d]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2], Max[c, d]}}, 
    {{x[1, 1], x[1, 2], Max[e, f]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2], Max[e, f]}}} *)

Per the comment, if the desire is to simply avoid computing max twice, then just wrap the expression that already works with With:
With[
  {max = Max[#]},
  Append[{max}, f[max]]] & /@ testlist


In your example the function does not take Max as the argument.

You didn't supply f, so I just came up with a dummy function that returns a "list of lists".

Essentially I want to have the same result as what Append[{Max[#]}, f[Max[#]]] & /@ testlist returns but without calling Max[...] twice.

The key point here is that the function fn should take Max as its argument, which is missing in your example.

In my example, my fn will take whatever you give it. It's just a dummy function. Replace fn in my example with your actual function.

The function fn wasn't part of the answer to your question. The following expression was the answer to your question, but I can't show a result without having a fn to work with.

The output I get with your code is {fn[{a, b, Max[a, b]}], fn[{c, d, Max[c, d]}], fn[{e, f, Max[e, f]}]}

But regardless, see my update.

Yes, that should probably work.

What version are you using? That should not be the output you get from my code.

I use the latest version. Here is my code: testlist = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}; Apply[Map[Append[#2], #1] &] /@ Comap[{fn, Max}] /@ testlist

Here is the output: {fn[{a, b, Max[a, b]}], fn[{c, d, Max[c, d]}], fn[{e, f, Max[e, f]}]}

I am fully satisfied with the With option, so I will assume for now that Map (/@) simply cannot do that.

Oh, you didn't use my definition of fn. So the Append just appends to the fn[...] expression. Append can work on things other than List. Since fn is undefined, it just sits there raw. That's why I supplied my own version of fn.

I see a problem now... your With solution appends Max to the output of f itself. However, I want it to be appended to every element of that output of f.

I literally just wrapped the code you wrote with With, so it seems the error was with your code. You will get much better help if you provide a minimal example with actual expected output. Also, you should try running the full code I supplied and explain why it doesn't work if it doesn't work.

Let's assume, just as an artificial example, that my function f is FactorInteger, as it also gives the same data structure. Let's assume the test input testlist = {{100, 200}, {300, 400}, {500, 600}}. Then my expected output should look like this: {{{2, 3, 200}, {5, 2, 200}}, {{2, 4, 400}, {5, 2, 400}}, {{2, 3, 600}, {3, 1, 600}, {5, 2, 600}}}.

I edited my initial question and added this example. I think that should be clear now.

To address the update to the question, here is a function that does the work (assuming yourFunction behaves like FactorInteger)
MapApply[Append]@*Thread@*Comap[{yourFunction, Identity}]@*Max

Demonstration:
testlist = {{100, 200}, {300, 400}, {500, 600}};
expected = {{{2, 3, 200}, {5, 2, 200}}, 
            {{2, 4, 400}, {5, 2, 400}}, 
            {{2, 3, 600}, {3, 1, 600}, {5, 2, 600}}};

oldFn = FactorInteger;
newFn = MapApply[Append]@*Thread@*Comap[{oldFn, Identity}]@*Max;

actual = newFn /@ testlist;

actual == expected
(* True *)

You could bundle this up into your own function generator:
fancy[fn_] := MapApply[Append]@*Thread@*Comap[{fn, Identity}]@*Max;

actual = fancy[FactorInteger] /@ testlist;
actual == expected
(* True *)


Thanks. Looks cryptic. Will test it tomorrow.

Everything worked well, your suggestion was really helpful.

glad to hear it!
